# Is there a matrix which is not orthogonal but only has A transpose A equal to identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Can there be a matrix $A$ with $A A^T  =  I$ and $A^T A \neq I$ ? If so give a 2x2 example of A

Comment: Welcome to Math.StackExchange. It's expected that askers here will not simply repost problems they've been given, but will instead show their work and describe what they are having trouble with.

Comment: It is possible to have a non-square matrix $A$ for which $AA^T = I$ but $A^T A \ne I$, but note that in this case the two $I$s are of different sizes.

Answer (score 4):

There are no such finite square matrices. The equation $AA^T=I$ implies that $A^T=A^{-1}$ and matrices commute with their inverse.

Answer (score 0):

$$A A^T  =  I$$
 $$A^{-1}A A^T  =  A^{-1}I=A^{-1}$$
 $$IA^T  =A^T = A^{-1}$$
 $$A^TA  =  A^{-1}A=I$$
 $$A^TA  =  AA^{T}=I$$